# find elements in two dictionaries based on criteria key in dictionary d1 should be value in d2 and vice versa

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries as below:

```
d1={
  11:8,
  12:24,
  21:12
}
d2={
  8:11,
  1:32,
  12:15
}
```

I need `11 8` as output as key in `d2` should match `d1` and vice versa.

```
key of d1 is value in d2
key of d2 is value in d1
```

Comment: Why not 12. It is a key in d2 and a value in d1?

Answer (score 0):

```
d1={
  11:8,
  12:24,
  21:12
}
d2={
  8:11,
  1:32,
  12:15
}

for i in d1:
    if d1[i] in d2:
        if d2[d1[i]]==i:
            print('{} {}'.format(i,d1[i]))
```

Try this hopefully it will work according to your expectation!

Answer (score 0):

```
for k, v in d1.items():
    if v in d2 and d2[v] == k:
        print(k, v)
```